# A functional equation for a Dirichlet series

Tags: functional-equations, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

I'm looking for a functional equation for the following Dirichlet series

$$\varphi(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{2 \cos(2n \pi q)}{n^s}}$$

where $q$ is a rational number.

Any help ?

Comment: $\varphi(s)=\text{Li}_s\big(e^{2iq\pi}\big)-\text{Li}_s\big(e^{-2iq\pi}\big)$.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that it has a functional equation? Because the coefficients $2\cos2\pi nq$ are periodic (with period $d$, the denominator of $q$), $\varphi(s)$ can be written as a linear combination of Dirichlet $L$-functions (mod $d$); each one individually has a functional equation, but they don't coincide (there are even and odd characters, and also nonprincipal characters).

Comment: I thought the linear combination will give an equation... Can you explicite the linear combination please ?

Comment: I believe the periodic zeta function has a known functional equation. Perhaps you could look this up?